# Why my docker-compose yaml file can't see jar file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this yaml file

```
version: '2'
services:
  app1:
    image: producer1
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    networks:
      - lognet1
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    networks:
      - lognet1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    networks:
      - lognet1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.99.100
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 2000000
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://192.168.99.100:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 0
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1


networks:
  lognet1:
    driver: overlay
```

and Docerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```

and jar in the same directory, but after compose upping it doesn't see new changes so it can't read jar,I tried so run them differently it worked,but with dcoker compose not

Comment: Please, post you `docker build` command line.

Comment: Run `docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up -d` and see if it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5790653/saeed Hi thanks a lot ,I've run them separately and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this command should work:

```
docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate app1
```

Else, run the second command:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache app1 && docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: tanks a lot )))